# How do I reinstall WSL ? Nothing works always same error

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

```
{Application Error}
The exception s (0x
```

whenever I try to start WSL it crashes and I can't find any way to fix it tried uninstalling it and installing it again but nothing works.

followed this guide to install
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10#step-4---download-the-linux-kernel-update-package

error message:

[image]

Installed distros

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[This reply](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5508#issuecomment-706052402) on github helped me

> I got rid of 0x8007023e by following steps
>
> 1. Disable all VM-like options (wsl, docker, vm platform, hyperv ...) in Turn Windows features on or off
> 2. Reboot
> 3. Enable WSL and Virtual Machine Platform
> 4. Reboot